# React Native set state an element of array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have an array in my state:

```
this.state = {
  data: [
    {
      quantity: 0
    }
  ],
  tempQuantity: 0
};
```

I want to update my `data[0].quantity` in a `TextInput` so i use:

```
onChangeText={tempQuantity =>
  this.setState({
    tempQuantity,
    data: [...this.state.data, { quantity: tempQuantity }]
  })
}
```

And i have a `<Text>` to show the result:

```
<View>
  <Text>{this.state.data[0].quantity}</Text>
</View>
```

But I get `0` every time!

1. How can I update each element of each object in an array?
2. If I use it this way, it will work dynamically? I mean i want to create an object (with all properties of the main object) every time I press a `<Button>`. [ for example: `data[0]` with `quantity` of 10 - `data[1] with`quantity` of 12 - and ...  ]

Comment: You are adding a new object to `data` on every `onChangeText`.

Comment: You are adding a new object to an array if you only have a single object in ``data`` array then why not add that as separate property in the state instead of an object inside data array.

Comment: @Tholle so how can I do this in correct way?

Comment: @Sandip it's simplified - i have about 15 properties

Comment: @MohamadKh75 Can you check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51758734/1904377.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a single event handler for every element in your array, you could pass in the `index` as well as the `event` and update the `quantity` for the element on that particular index.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      {
        quantity: 0
      },
      {
        quantity: 10
      },
      {
        quantity: 100
      }
    ]
  };

  handleChange = (event, index) => {
    const { value } = event.target;

    this.setState(previousState => {
      const data = [...previousState.data];

      data[index] = {...data[index], quantity: value };

      return { data };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map((element, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <input
              type="number"
              value={element.quantity}
              onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, index)}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your `data` array before setting it to state. You can do it in the following way:

Suppose you have an array with following items:

```
var data = [
{name: 'a', age: 12},
{name: 'b', age: 15}
]
```

You need to modify it before setting to state again in the following way:

```
var newData = data.map((item) => {
return {...item, age: 20}
})
```

Now your `newData` will be

```
var newData = [
{name: 'a', age: 20},
{name: 'b', age: 20}
]
```

This `newData` can be assigned to `state`.

Comment: This is an answer for the question 1? So how can I add new object to my array? I want this to be dynamic... (question 2)

Comment: I want to edit the age of object[x] not to change all of them to 20!

Comment: @MohamadKh75 If you want to update object[x], then you need to update it directly at that index. Like ``object[x].age = newValue``.

Comment: @MohamadKh75 for your question ``So how can I add new object to my array?`` whatever you are doing was fine for it, it will add new object to existing state array.